# Why is the input file format affecting my execution time so much?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, matrix-multiplication

**DESCRIPTION:**

I've been working on a project involving matrix multiplication and Hadoop. I've ran my MapReduce code using both a Single Node and a Multi Node cluster setup and I've encountered some results that I'm not sure I can explain (likely due to my lack of Hadoop expertise, hence the posted question). In case it is relevant, my cluster has one master node and four slave nodes. Here is a diagram I put together of how my MapReduce program works for the multiplication of a 2x2 matrix:

[image]

Naturally, the input is formatted to represent a matrix, so `a,0,0,1` represents that there is a value of `1` in location `0,0` of matrix `A`.

**RESULTS**

I began by running matrices that have equivalent number of elements but different dimensions. I found that the "more square" the matrices were, the quicker the jobs executed. This makes sense to me: if we have a `[20000x2][2x20000]` multiplication, this is going to result in 4 different "segments" (excuse my poor terminology) in our reducer, each with 40000 elements, compared to a `[200x200][200x200]` matrix, in which there will be 200 segments, each with 200 elements. Since all of the actual multiplication occurs sequentially in the reducer, having fewer segments with more elements should take longer because there is less that can be parallelized.

The next thing I began to think about was the impact that my input file format had on the execution. There were essentially three different input formats I wanted to try. The first two are what I am calling "row major" and "column major". I generated the matrices with this code (by switching the row and column variables, respectively):

```
    for (int m = 0; m < 200; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
            writer.println(String.format("a,%d,%d,%.4f", m, n, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 100)));
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < 200; p++) {
            writerB.println(String.format("b,%d,%d,%.4f", n, p, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 100)));
        }
    }
```

This resulted in file formats that look like this:

```
Row Major 
--------- 
a,0,0,20.2074
a,0,1,29.3252
a,0,2,64.5026
a,0,3,53.9574
a,0,4,29.3813
a,0,5,13.1202
a,0,6,52.8259
a,0,7,60.0963
a,0,8,11.6382
a,0,9,88.7868

Col Major
-------------
a,0,0,92.2614
a,1,0,0.1070
a,2,0,14.4420
a,3,0,97.3052
a,4,0,15.5435
a,5,0,51.5586
a,6,0,63.3186
a,7,0,84.0014
a,8,0,63.0877
a,9,0,90.8724
```

I tried one more format as well, which I'm calling "distributed". Here's the generating code:

```
    for (int m = 0; m < 200; m++) {
        int n = 0;
        while(n <= m) {
            writer.println(String.format("a,%d,%d,%.4f", m, n++, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 100)));
        }
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < 200; n++) {
        int p = 0;
        while(p <= n) {
            writerB.println(String.format("b,%d,%d,%.4f", n, p++, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(0, 100)));
        }
    }
```

And the resulting file output:

```
Distributed
-----------
a,0,0,69.0747
a,1,0,23.2568
a,1,1,39.1628
a,2,0,12.7795
a,2,1,54.9023
a,2,2,47.7321
a,3,0,39.5109
a,3,1,16.6630
a,3,2,7.5520
a,3,3,17.2945
```

To my surprise, the performance from the distributed file format was **significantly better** than that of the row or column major format! In fact, the output of my row and column major formatted files was so mediocre that it was comparable to the output of multiplying the `[20000x2][2x20000]` matrices. I thought this might just be the case when *both* matrices were row major or *both* were column major, but when I tried multiplying a row major matrix `A` with a column major matrix `B` (or vise versa), I got similar results. To give some concrete example of what I'm talking about, here are some of my results from the multinode cluster:

```
[20000x2][2x20000] Multiplication Duration: 80867 ms
[200x200][200x200] Row Major Duration:      71845 ms
[200x200][200x200] Distributed Duration:    29929 ms
```

**QUESTION**

Why does the format of the input file have such a dramatic effect on the time it takes to complete the MapReduce process? Does the format impact the way that information is distributed in the HDFS? Why are the square matrices with row/col major formats taking nearly the same time as very non-square matrices, while matrices with the distributed format only take around a third of the time to execute? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.